What's wrong with this quick sort?
I tried to adapt this example from K&R (5.11, ANSI edition) to sort an array of ints but it crashes randomly and I can't figure why.
The original version sorted "lines" : char *lineptr[1000], I'm trying to sort int *p or int p[4]. I would like to keep the most generic parameters possible and I guess it's where my problem comes from.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUMS 4

int numcmp(int* a, int* b);
void mqsort(void* v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void*, void*));
void swap(void* v[], int i, int j);

int numcmp(int* a, int* b) {
  return *a - *b;
}

void swap(void* v[], int i, int j) {
  printf("swap befor %d: %d, %d: %d\n", i, v[i], j, v[j]);
  void* temp;
  temp = v[i];
  v[i] = v[j];
  v[j] = temp;
  printf("swap after %d: %d, %d: %d\n", i, v[i], j, v[j]);
}

void mqsort(void* v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void*, void*)) {
  int i, last;

  if (left >= right) {
    return;
  }

  printf("left %d, right %d\n", left, right);
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    printf("%d, ", v[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);

  last = left;
  for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
    if ((*comp)(v[i], v[left]) < 0) {
      ++last;
      swap(v, last, i);
    }
  }
  swap(v, left, last);
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    printf("%d, ", v[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  mqsort(v, left, last - 1, comp);
  mqsort(v, last + 1, right, comp);
}
int main(void) {
  int i;
  /* doesn't work :( */
  /* int* p; */
  /* int* p_start; */
  /* p_start = p = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAXNUMS); */
  /* if (p == NULL) { */
  /*   printf("cannot allocate"); */
  /*   exit(1); */
  /* } */
  /* *(p + 0) = 1; */
  /* *(p + 1) = 3; */
  /* *(p + 2) = 5; */
  /* *(p + 3) = 7; */

  int p[MAXNUMS] = {1, 3, 5, 7};

  for (i = 0; i < MAXNUMS; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", p[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  mqsort((void**)p, 0, MAXNUMS - 1, (int (*)(void*, void*))numcmp);

  for (i = 0; i < MAXNUMS; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", p[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  /* free(p); */
  /* free(p_start); */

  return 0;
}

Here's a link to a working version and to the example itself, page 100.
I tried to bypass the comp function completely, I also tried to change the pivot, I tried many versions of numcmp like int numcmp(int a, int b), int numcmp(int *a, int *b) but nothing works.
I always get random numbers after execution.
I really can't figure what's wrong and where do those numbers come from.
Obviously, when I just use mqsort(int* p, int start, int right) and a comparison, it works fine :)

You do not have an array of pointers.

Please compile with warnings enabled: there are many, to do with printf format string and argument incompatibility.

@stark
That's exactly the problem.
Thanks a lot.
Make it an answer and I'll credit you.
I made it work with :
  int numbers[MAXNUMS] = {1, 5, 3, 7};
  int* int_pointers[MAXNUMS];

  for (int i = 0; i < MAXNUMS; i++) {
    int_pointers[i] = &numbers[i];
  }


How does mqsort know the size of elements in the array it's supposed to sort?

@Chris I think the array is supposed to be an array of pointers to the actual data elements, but based on the description, I do not think the OP understood that before posting the question.

As a rule of thumb, beginners should not use the cast operator anywhere. In this case it is pretty much either creating bugs or hiding bugs.

@nielsen exactly. The first comment opened my eyes.
I'm following the book and tried to adapt their example. They basically said the same thing : casting may be hard to debug.

Thanks for all the answers. I had to chose one, since I can't accept both.

Your code has a minor error, which is that the array needs to consist of int * rather than int.  So, in main, change
int p[MAXNUMS] = {1, 3, 5, 7};

to
int ip[] = {1, 3, 5, 7};
int *p[MAXNUMS] = {&ip[0], &ip[1], &ip[2], &ip[3]};

That and fixing the printfs to use correct parameters and formats fixes your code:
1, 3, 5, 7, 
left 0, right 3
0x7ffe434e26e0, 0x7ffe434e26e4, 0x7ffe434e26e8, 0x7ffe434e26ec, 
swap befor 0: 0x7ffe434e26e0, 1: 0x7ffe434e26e4
swap after 0: 0x7ffe434e26e4, 1: 0x7ffe434e26e0
swap befor 1: 0x7ffe434e26e0, 1: 0x7ffe434e26e0
swap after 1: 0x7ffe434e26e0, 1: 0x7ffe434e26e0
swap befor 0: 0x7ffe434e26e4, 1: 0x7ffe434e26e0
swap after 0: 0x7ffe434e26e0, 1: 0x7ffe434e26e4
0x7ffe434e26e0, 0x7ffe434e26e4, 0x7ffe434e26e8, 0x7ffe434e26ec, 
left 2, right 3
0x7ffe434e26e0, 0x7ffe434e26e4, 0x7ffe434e26e8, 0x7ffe434e26ec, 
swap befor 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8, 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8
swap after 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8, 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8
swap befor 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8, 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8
swap after 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8, 2: 0x7ffe434e26e8
0x7ffe434e26e0, 0x7ffe434e26e4, 0x7ffe434e26e8, 0x7ffe434e26ec, 
1, 3, 5, 7, 


There are several problems with the code.
The most severe one is that void* is the only pointer in C which has some generic abilities and can get assigned to/from any other object pointer type. That special ability does not apply "recursively" to void**.
Furthermore, there is no such generic pointer type for function pointers at all. You cannot cast an int (*) (int*, int*) function pointer to/from a int (*)(void*, void*), that's an undefined behavior bug.
In general, the wild casting everywhere is the source of all problems. Do not use casts unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing.
So (void**)p is nonsense, it should just be p and mqsort needs to have the parameter list rewritten.
As is (int (*)(void*, void*))numcmp - the problem here is that you've implemented numcmp incorrectly. Rather than taking int pointer parameters, it has to be:
int numcmp(const * a, const* b) {

  return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

Also please keep in mind that just a - b is naive, since that expression can overflow/underflow easily. A safer implementation would be:
int numcmp(const * a, const* b) {
  int ia = (int*)a;
  int ib = (int*)b;

  if(ia < ib)
    return -1;
  if(ib < ia)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

As for the mqsort, I don't see why it should be mqsort(void* v[] ... since it isn't dealing with an array of pointers, just an array. Drop the [].
You also have some 10+ compiler warnings from wrong printf parameters, mostly because you try to print void* when you meant int and the like. Compile with all warnings enabled.
